# Spring3 exclude binding form field

Tags: java, spring

I have this question. Suppose in the `jsp` form I have some hidden field:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="TrainingInstructorForm">
<form:hidden name="tmpFileID" />
</form:form>
```

I want that the `tmpFileID` will not be bound to the `TrainingInstructorForm` as this is not part of the `TrainingInstructorForm` domain model and rather a convenience thing for communicating information from the user to the controller. I intend to access this using:

```
@RequestMapping(value="..")
public String submit(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String tmpFileId = request.getParameter("tmpFileId);
}
```

How can I tell the `spring` framework which fields to go for binding and which fields not in addition of them being available to the `http servlet` request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If tmpFileID is not part of TrainingInstructorForm, then make it as input type rather than bind by spring form input tag which will bind tagged fields to form.

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="TrainingInstructorForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="tmpFileID" value="something"/>
    </form:form>
```